# visual studio code Intellisense for Javascript(React) is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My vs code intellisense is suddenly stopped suggesting things for my react.js files, it is not even recognizing little things like , className etc.
[image]

Comment: it works when I rename it to .jsx from .js but it previously used to work on all files irrespective of js or jsx extention

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the file with the `.jsx` extension

Comment: but it was previously working in .js extention